# How to know the length of a key and the key itself in the context of Friedman test and Vigenere cipher

Tags: cryptography, key, vigenere

The title says it all... I can't seem to get the idea... I know it uses the index of coincidence but I'm not sure with whom or what am I supposed to compare it with... How is the formula used?... It would help me a lot if it were exposed in an algorithmic representation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link should probably light up your mind...

http://practicalcryptography.com/cryptanalysis/stochastic-searching/cryptanalysis-vigenere-cipher/

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the book Cryptography Theory and Practice Third Edition, and it's horrible. It states the formula but never a concrete example.